# Setting up Laravel 5.1 with Behat

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.1, behat

Following the Laracast tutorial I ran the following command to set up my project for behat:

```
composer require behat/behat behat/mink behat/mink-extension laracasts/behat-laravel-extension --dev
```

This is the output I received:

```
Using version ^3.0 for behat/behat
Using version ^1.7 for behat/mink
Using version ^2.1 for behat/mink-extension
Using version ^1.0 for laracasts/behat-laravel-extension
./composer.json has been updated
> php artisan clear-compiled
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install behat/behat v3.0.15
    - Conclusion: don't install behat/behat v3.0.14
    - Conclusion: don't install behat/behat v3.0.13
    - Conclusion: don't install behat/behat v3.0.12
    - Conclusion: don't install behat/behat v3.0.11
    - Conclusion: don't install behat/behat v3.0.10
    - Conclusion: don't install behat/behat v3.0.9
    - Conclusion: don't install behat/behat v3.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install behat/behat v3.0.7
    - behat/mink-extension v2.1.0 requires behat/behat ~3.0,>=3.0.5 -> satisfiable by behat/behat[v3.0.10, v3.0.11, v3.0.12, v3.0.13, v3.0.14, v3.0.15, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9].
    - Conclusion: don't install behat/behat v3.0.6
    - Installation request for behat/mink-extension ^2.1 -> satisfiable by behat/mink-extension[v2.1.0].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/yaml v3.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v3.0.1
    - behat/behat v3.0.5 requires symfony/yaml ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/yaml[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.1.0, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.1.1, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.1.10, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.1.11, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.1.12, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.1.13, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.1.2, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.1.3, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.1.4, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.1.5, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.1.6, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.1.7, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.1.8, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.1.9, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.2.0, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.2.1, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.2.10, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.2.11, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.2.2, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.2.3, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.2.4, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.2.5, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.2.6, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.2.7, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.2.8, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.2.9, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.0, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.1, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.10, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.11, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.12, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.13, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.14, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.15, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.16, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.17, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.18, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.19, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.2, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.20, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.21, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.22, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.23, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.24, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.25, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.26, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.27, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.28, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.29, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.3, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.30, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.31, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.32, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.33, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.34, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.35, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.36, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.37, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.4, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.5, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.6, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.7, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.8, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.3.9, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.4.0, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.4.1, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.4.10, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.4.2, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.4.3, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.4.4, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.4.5, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.4.6, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.4.7, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.4.8, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.4.9, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.5.0, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.5.1, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.5.10, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.5.11, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.5.12, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.5.2, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.5.3, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.5.4, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.5.5, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.5.6, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.5.7, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.5.8, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.5.9, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.6.0, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.6.1, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.6.10, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.6.11, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.6.12, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.6.13, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.6.2, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.6.3, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.6.4, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.6.5, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.6.6, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.6.7, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.6.8, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.6.9, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.7.0, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.7.1, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.7.2, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.7.3, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.7.4, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.7.5, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.7.6, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.7.7, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.7.8, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.7.9, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.8.0, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.8.1, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v2.8.2, v3.0.1].
    - Installation request for symfony/yaml == 3.0.1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/yaml[v3.0.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without Laravel**

Ok, i removed the `--dev` from your Composer command and it worked

`composer require behat/behat behat/mink behat/mink-extension laracasts/behat-laravel-extension --prefer-dist -vvv --profile`

The resulting `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "behat/behat": "^3.0",
        "behat/mink": "^1.7",
        "behat/mink-extension": "^2.1",
        "laracasts/behat-laravel-extension": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

**With Laravel (project install)**

If you need Laravel: just add `laravel/laravel` to the command

or add `"laravel/laravel" : "^5.2"` (or 5.1) as a requirement.

The resulting `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "behat/behat": "^3.0",
        "behat/mink": "^1.7",
        "behat/mink-extension": "^2.1",
        "laracasts/behat-laravel-extension": "^1.0",
        "laravel/laravel": "^5.2"
    }
}
```